# Set html attribute as javascript for custom event

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, event-handling, custom-events

This works fine:

```
<div id='clicker' onclick='alert("clicked")'>clicker</div>
<script> $('#clicker').trigger('click'); </script>
```

How can I make this work ( without using eval )?

```
<div id='clacker' onclack='alert("clacked")'>clacker</div>
<script> $('#clacker').trigger('clack'); </script>
```

Trying to mimic the behavior of the inline onclick attribute, but with my own custom attribute/event, to apply a simple solution to a simple problem.

Comment: I see two issues with what is going on.

Your inline script on the second example doesn't know what clack is, the only reason click works is because .trigger has a special case for that word.

Try looking at this option instead of eval: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

What is the use case of you 'onclack' function? If you need to call multiple functions on a click, then you can chain multiple functions in `onclick`, otherwise you can create a custom property, such as `foofunction="bar"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't create custom attributes like this. Only the built-in events have corresponding `on<event>` attributes.

Create an event handler using jQuery `.on()` or JavaScript `.addEventListener()`.

```js
$("#clacker").on("clack", function() {
  alert('clacked');
});

$('#clacker').trigger('clack');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='clacker'>clacker</div>
```